# How to send images in email through django

Tags: django

This is in my views.py :

```
subject='Thank you for your order from cottgin.in'
message=f'Your order id is {a}'
from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
to_list=[order.customer.user.email]
send_mail(subject,message,from_email,to_list,fail_silently=True)
```

I am sending the order info to the user after he places the order but I also want to send some images like the item images as well as the logo . how do i do that.Can I send a html template in mail? I havent found any proper solution to this on internet so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

as per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types) to send HTML e-mail you need to use alternative content-types, like this:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

For more information please read docs carefully :)

Also, you can have HTML template in you templates folder for it and do:

```
ctx = Context({ 'your_data': 'Hello World' })
email_tpl = get_template('email_tpl.html')    
html_content = email_tpl.render(ctx)
```